# Android: get route info programmatically

Tags: android, routetable

I am sending UDP packets to a remote, and I would like to know the IP of the local interface that will be used for that. In a shell I would run:

```sh
ip route get 192.168.1.54
```

and it would answer something like:

```
192.168.1.12 dev wlan0  table local_network  src 192.168.1.1
```

Where I'm interested in getting the `src`: `192.168.1.1`.

I can do it by calling `exec` like this:

```kotlin
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ip route get 192.168.1.54")
```

but that does not seem very elegant and I don't know which devices support that (it works on some of them, and others return an error code "1" though the command works in `adb shell`).

Is there a way to do that with the Android SDK? I looked at the `ConnectivityManager` but could not find a way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want the address of the network's gateway for your WiFi network.

This function is based on [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/LinkProperties) and some [examples](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.net.ConnectivityManager&method=getLinkProperties).

```
public InetAddress getGateway(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =
            (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        // getActiveNetwork() requires M or later.
        return null;
    }
    Network activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork();
    if (activeNetwork == null) {
        return null;
    }
    List<RouteInfo> routes = connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(activeNetwork).getRoutes();
    for (RouteInfo route : routes) {
        if (route.isDefaultRoute() && !(route.getGateway() instanceof Inet6Address)) {
           return route.getGateway();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Android's [DatagramSocket](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/DatagramSocket) should directly provide you with source address:

```kt
val socket = DatagramSocket()
val targetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(destHostOrIp)
socket.connect(targetAddress, port)
val local = socket.getLocalAddress()
```